# calculate the difference between two datetimes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two primefaces calendar component as following :

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{prezmsg['MAINTENANCE.DATE_DEBUT']}"/>
<p:calendar id="dateDebut-create"
            value="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.vo.dateDebut}"
            pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" mask="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.dateDiff}"/>
</p:calendar>
<p:message for="dateDebut-create"/>

<h:outputLabel value="#{prezmsg['MAINTENANCE.DATE_FIN']}"/>
<p:calendar id="dateFin-create"
            value="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.vo.dateFin}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            mask="true">
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.dateDiff}"/>
</p:calendar>
<p:message for="dateFin-create"/>
```

so I want to calculate the difference in only time between these two calendar components, and put the value in another calendar which is time only.

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{prezmsg['MAINTENANCE.DUREE']}"/>
                <p:calendar id="duree-create" value="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.vo.duree}" pattern="HH:mm:ss"
                            timeOnly="true" readonly="true"/>
                <p:message for="duree-create"/>
```

When I select the start date and the end date this function is triggered :

```
public void dateDiff(SelectEvent event){
        if(getVo().getDateDebut() != null && getVo().getDateFin() != null){

            Date calculatedTime = null;
            long diff = getVo().getDateFin().getTime() - getVo().getDateDebut().getTime();
            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

            try {
                calculatedTime =  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(diffHours+":"+diffMinutes+":"+diffSeconds);
                System.out.print("Calculated Time : " + calculatedTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getVo().setDuree(calculatedTime);
        }
    }
```

so in console I've this message : `Calculated Time : Fri Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 1970` and I no value for the third componenet is set.

Comment: So the actual question was how to update a component after an ajax request. Your title is so wrong, did you notice that? And if you can ask the core question, most likely you'd have found a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ajax event needs to `update` third calendar component once you've calculated the difference:

```
<p:ajax event="dateSelect" 
listener="#{maintenanceMBean.webBean.dateDiff}" update="duree-create"/>
```